# CSS files not loading in django

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

This is my first Django project. I cannot load CSS files onto my website. i've done everything possible.

```
Project Directries

firstproject/
  assets/
  static/
    css/
      <CSS files>
```

Settings.py/ static files

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILE_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'assets')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns  += static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

HTML file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap-grid.css' %}">
```

Comment: where is `assets` folder? STATIC_ROOT points to it. how is BASE_DIR initialized? DEBUG = true or false?

Comment: Is your link in the head of your HTML file?

Comment: I forgot to mention assets in the code. but it is there, and DEBUG is set to TRUE.

Comment: Yes Link in head of HTML file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you made spelling mistake in staticfilesdirs in settings.py file.

Change this:

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILE_DIRS = [ #Here you made spelling mistake. It should be  `STATICFILES_DIRS`
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
]
```

To this:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
```

And in link tag just add `type="text/css"`.